I need to index a GTF (gene transfer format) annotation file
This question was also asked on Biostars
I created a GTF file for HLA alleles to be used as a resource for GATK Funcotator. Running Funcotator without indexing the GTF gives this error:
A USER ERROR has occurred: Input funcotator_dataSources.v1.7.20200521s/gencode/hla/hla.annotation.gtf must support random access to enable queries by interval. If it's a file, please index it using the bundled tool IndexFeatureFile

The first few lines of GTF file:
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  gene    1   3503    .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; source "IMGHLA";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  transcript  1   3503    .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    301 373 .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number "1"; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_1";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    504 773 .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number "2"; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_2";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    1015    1290    .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number "3"; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_3";

I need to index this file before running Funcotator. I tried using the GATK IndexFeatureFile, as suggested by Funcotator but it gives this error:
A USER ERROR has occurred: Unknown file is malformed: Decoded feature is not valid: hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  gene    1   3503    .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01";  source "IMGHLA";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  transcript  1   3503    .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    301 373 .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number 1; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_1";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    504 773 .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number 2; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_2";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    1015    1290    .   +   .   gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number 3; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_3";

Can someone suggest a solution for this or an alternate tool to index the GTF file?

I am not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but the seq_id (column1) seems to be identical to the gene_id value, which is unusual

Please link us to the actual file so we can check the format and also show us the full command you used. Does the file have windows line endings perhaps? Was it ever opened in Windows? Could it have spaces instead of tabs separating the fields?

cross posted https://www.biostars.org/p/9602494/ gene_type is missing

Ah, thanks @Pierre! That's really weird though, why would they do that? Everything in the attributes field (including the attributes field itself) is optional so it is very off that GATK would choke on this.

As Pierre Lindenbaum  pointed out in your duplicate question on Biostars, GATK's function that checks the validity of a GTF feature fails if gene_type is missing (source):
 private static boolean validateBaseGtfFeatureFields(final GencodeGtfFeature feature) {

[...]
       if (feature.getGeneType() == null) {
            return false;
        }
[...]
}

This function, validateBaseGtfFeatureFields is called as part of function validateFeature (source):
private boolean validateFeature(final GencodeGtfFeature feature) {
        return validateBaseGtfFeatureFields(feature) && validateFeatureSubtype(feature);
    }

Which in turn is called when reading a GTF file and the code will exit with the error you saw if validateFeatureSubtype returns false (source):
  // Now we validate our feature before returning it:
 if ( ! validateFeature(decodedFeature) ) {
    throw new UserException.MalformedFile("Decoded feature is not valid: " + decodedFeature);
 }

All this means that you need to have gene_type set in your file. You can do this with the following sed command on a Linux machine:
sed -i.bak 's/(.*\t)/\1gene_type none; /' file.gtf 

Or, on a macOS machine, use:
sed -i .bak 's/(.*\t)/\1gene_type none; /' file.gtf 

This looks for the last tab (\t) character on each line and adds the string  gene_type none after it. Running it on your example file produces:
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  gene    1   3503    .   +   .   gene_type none; gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; source "IMGHLA";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  transcript  1   3503    .   +   .   gene_type none; gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    301 373 .   +   .   gene_type none; gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number "1"; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_1";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    504 773 .   +   .   gene_type none; gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number "2"; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_2";
hla_a_01_01_01_01   IMGHLA  exon    1015    1290    .   +   .   gene_type none; gene_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; gene_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01"; transcript_name "hla_a_01_01_01_01.1"; exon_number "3"; exon_id "hla_a_01_01_01_01_e_3";

And this is now recognized by IndexFeatureFile.
Important: this assumes that this is the only missing element and that it is missing on all lines. If this is not the case, please update your question and show us a more comprehensive input example.
Finally, I would consider this a bug in GATK and report it to them. The GTF specification makes it quite clear that the entire attributes field (the last field) is optional:

Column 9: “attributes”
A list of feature attributes in the format tag=value. Multiple tag=value pairs are separated by semicolons. URL escaping rules are used for tags or values containing the following characters: “,=;”. Spaces are allowed in this field, but tabs must be replaced with the %09 URL escape. This field is not required.

So a program failing because an optional field which is actually present simply doesn't contain one specific, also optional sub-field is very odd.
